# Ruby on Rails global categories block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ROR and I don't understand how can I make global template which I could put in any other template. For example I have categories module and would like to create sidebar navigation and put it at homepage template. I tried to do it this way, but categories controller method side_nav is never called. Is this good practice for this type of problem or should i do it different way?

**categories/categories_controller.rb**

```
def side_nav
    @categories = Category.all
end
```

**categories/_side_nav.html.erb**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <% categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.title, category.title.downcase %></li>
  <% end %> 
</ul>
```

**homepage/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'categories/side_nav' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at layout/application file. It's global layout in your custom project by default. And you can provide your custom layouts in your contollers.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: As well you may want to check code convention for Ruby. 'cause in Ruby developers used to us soft tabulation.
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide